# Remove single spaces from lines, but leave multiple spaces alone

Tags: shell, awk, sed, cut

I have the following input:

```
a a f  aa
aa  aa a h o
f  j
```

The above input has single spaces as well as multiple spaces. I need to remove only the single ones, not the others, i.e. the output should be

```
aaf  aa
aa  aaaho
f  j
```

Comment: Please make an effort to solve your own problems before you post them here.

Answer (score 3):

Perl to the rescue!

```
perl -pe 's/(?<! ) (?! )//g' < input
```

- `(?<! )` is a negative look-behind assertion. It matches if the preceding string is not matched, i.e. in this case, it's not a space.
- `(?! )` is a negative look-ahead assertion. Similar to the above, but looks to the right.

Answer (score 0):

Lex to the rescue!

```
$ cat x.l
%%
" "" "+ ECHO;
" "     /* do nothing = don't echo */
%%
int yywrap(void)
{
  return 1;
}
int main(void)
{
  yylex();
  return 0;
}
$ lex x.l
$ cc lex.yy.c -o spacedel
$ ./spacedel < in
aaf  aa
aa  aaaho
f  j
```

This lex specification says to create a C program that echoes all sequences of two or more spaces; ignore single spaces; and the default rule for unmatched characters is to echo them, which is exactly what we want.
(You could append `. ECHO;` if you want to make this explicit).

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed 's/\b\s\b//g' file
```

This removes a single white space surrounded by word boundaries.